# Is there any way to output all configuration options in my configuration.nix?

Tags: nixos

I want to set up jetty on nixos. I can install it through system.systemPackages but I can't get it to autostart (services.jetty isn't defined)

I don't want to ask every option here, so I want to know if there is documentation or a way to print every option under services?

I looked [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/servers/http/jetty), and I can't find anything there either

Answer (score 3):

To answer the title of your question; the NixOS `nixos-option` utility program will let you query what attributes of your `configuration.nix` evaluate to.

I don't know if NixOS explicitly provides a way to print the whole thing, but you could probably do it yourself fairly easily by using [the same function](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/lib/eval-config.nix) NixOS uses internally to evaluate configuration.nix. IIRC you would need to call it with `{ modules = [ /etc/nixos/configuration.nix ]; }`. You could then make use of Nix's built in `toXML` functionality to get the evaluated config to a printable string. `builtins.toXML` or the `--xml` flag to `nix-instantiate` are both possible ways to access that functionality.

I should say that if you do that there will be *a lot* of xml.

But I think that's not actually the body of your question. It sounds like you just want to check what all the available predefined NixOS services are? The [configuration options appendix](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html) to the [NixOS manual](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/) lists that info.

However if you're after a service unit for Jetty it appears there currently isn't one.

I don't know anything about Jetty but I imagine you could write your own pretty easily (I've written a few for myself and found it fairly straightforward). [This entry on the NixOS wiki](https://nixos.org/wiki/NixOS:extend_NixOS#Using_systemd) gives an example of a nixos systemd service unit. You can also look through [all the other NixOS modules](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/nixos/modules) to follow how they're written. And of course consult the relevant systemd man pages also.

On a side note, if you do that you'll find you don't need to declare a module binary in `systemPackages`, because its path gets pulled into its systemd unit, so you just interact with it there instead.

Comment: Not the questioner but mine was what you answered in first part, thank you.

Comment: I've tried the way mentioned in the first part of the answer and as of this comment, the `toXML` part fails with an error indicating that static enumeration of that expression is not possible.

Comment: @0fnt there's likely something in your expression that can't be converted into an xml representation. You can use `nix-repl` to evaluate parts of your expressions and see which part is responsible.

Comment: What about flake-based systems?